# Can I resize a filesystem without resizing the partion in advance?

Tags: linux, filesystems, sles, ext3

Quick question: Can I resize a filesystem without resizing the partition in advance? The question aims at growing, but information on shrinking might be useful for future reference too.

Here's the scenario:

- SLES VM running on vSphere
- Extend virtual disk to bigger size
- The disk has a single partition but no LVM
- Log into SLES VM and run the following commands:

  - Perform SCSI rescan: `echo '1' > /sys/class/scsi_disk/<foobar>/device/rescan`
  - Verify extended disk: `fdisk -l`
  - Resize filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/foo`
- Result: Filesystem successfully resized

A colleague told me about this and did it, but I was sure that it **have to**  resize the partition with `fdisk` or similar in advance as pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime/119458#119458).

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) certainly *shrink* a filesystem before shrinking the partition, though not necessarily - if you shrink the partition first, unless you create a new partition, nothing *should* write to the new empty space, but it still feels dangerous.

If you are talking about growing the filesystem, you can overwrite some space following the partition (e.g. with superblock copies). Again, it *could* work if nothing writes to the (officially) empty space before resizing the filesystem, but `resize2fs` will normally not grow beyond the size of the partition.

Note that your example looks like resizing the whole disk and using the filesystem in partitionless mode. In that case, shrinking the disk size before the filesystem might (and likely will) result in filesystem corruption, while growing the filesystem has to be done after you extend the disk size.

Comment: Shrinking the partition first means that any portion of the file system after the partition end will become inaccessible; so even if nothing writes to the empty space, you’re liable to run into problems (including not being able to shrink the file system).

Comment: @StephenKitt Not if the kernel fails to reload the partition table - which is quite likely if the filesystem on the partition remains mounted (or you modify the partition table and do not tell the kernel - i.e. *not* by `parted` or `fdisk`, but a disk editor or something). Regardless, this is not something I would recommend.

Comment: Right, it ends up relying on a few happy coincidences ;-).

Comment: Hi @RadovanGarabík and thanks for your input. Sadly I knew the stuff you pointed out so I clarified my question a little. I am focused on growing and I am especially curious about the exact chain of commands as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Thorian93 Yes, if your disk really has a single partition, then you should resize it first. However, are you sure there is a partition? What exactly is your `/dev/foo` ? Chances are, you do not have any partitions and then of course, there is no partition to resize.

Comment: Ah, now I see your point I think. And that partially answers my question. I will update on that assumption tomorrow. But just assume for a minute that there actually was a partition, then the described procedure wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @Thorian93 well, in that case `fdisk` would show unchanged partition size and a free space. You would probably get around that by specifying manually the size for `resize2fs` and the `-f`` parameter. But that would leave you with a dangerous situation - writing anything to that free space would overwrite your filesystem,

Comment: You were right, there is no partition on that particular disk. So to wrap this up: If you have a partition on a disk you have to extend the partition prior to extending the filesystem. If there is no partition you are able to directly resize the filesystem as described in my initial question. Right?